# Как задать формат печати страницы фрейма?

Tags: javascript, css, css3

подскажите с такой проблемкой, есть две ссылки по которым печатаются данные из фреймов, с одной ссылки необходимо печатать страницы формата А5 Альбомная, вторая ссылка печать А4 Книжная. Не получается никак настроить через стили CSS

```html
<a onclick="window.frames['printj'].print();">Печать А5 </a>
<iframe style="display: none;" id="printj" name="printj" src="/link/A5"></iframe>

<a onclick="window.frames['printk'].print();">Печать А4 </a>
<iframe style="display: none;" id="printk" name="printk" src="/link/A4"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Формат листа нельзя задать из css или js. Только в меню печати браузера